# iOS 10.3 text to speech works on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, text-to-speech

I'm calling text to speech for the French language.

This works as expected on: `iOS 9.3` simulator, `iOS 9.3` device (`iPad 3rd gen`), `iOS 10.3` simulator.
Does not work (silently) on `iOS 10.3` device (`iPhone 6s`).

Default French voice is installed and works according to device settings.

```
static AVSpeechSynthesizer* synthesizer = NULL;
//...
+(void)readText:(NSString*)text
{
    if(synthesizer == NULL)
      synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:text];
    utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"fr-FR"];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
}
```

Comment: Please check your device is silent mode or not. Also check device volume by volume up down buttons.

Comment: This was my issue... i didnt know that it did that because my videos were all playing fine.... ugh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the speech synthesizer is controlled by the ringer volume, not the media volume. The ringer was muted on the tester's device.

Answer (score 0):

on your .h file 
add `AVSpeechSynthesizer* synthesizer = NULL;`
 and you're good to go-- i have tested it.. it works super fine :)

go to your .h file and add

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer* synthesizer = NULL;
```

and on the .m one

```
-(void)readText:(NSString*)text
{
    if(synthesizer == NULL)
      synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:text];
    utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"fr-FR"];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
}
```