# Swift Text to Speech doesn't work on device, but does work on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, text-to-speech

The problem is: I have an implementation of the textToSpeech on swift and weirdly it doesn't work on my iPhone, but when I use the simulator it does!

Here's a simple code:

```
    import UIKit
    import AVFoundation

    class ViewController: UIViewController, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }

        @IBAction func buttonPushed(sender: UIButton) {
            let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string:"This is a test")
            utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
            let voice = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
            voice.delegate = self
            voice.speak(utterance)
        }
    }
```

It used to work before I update my xcode to version 9.2, so I don't know what to do. Spent the whole day on this and nothing!
Weirdly, have another view controller which I use for recording voice and pass it to text (speechToText) and when I try this, then the textToSpeech start working on my iPhone, that's the only way it works. I don't know why as my textToSpeech and speechToText are in different view controllers and they are not related.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Your code is working fine in device also.

Comment: Check volume of iPhone or Restart once or try in earphone.

Comment: It doesn't work mate! Volume on my iPhone is fine I tried already switching to iTunes and playing a song and it works fine. I already restarted xcode and iPhone and still doesn't work! Something I didn't mention is that I have another view controller which I use for record voice and pass it to text (speechToText) and I try this, then the textToSpeech start working. I don't know why as they are in different view controllers.

Comment: So if it works in another view controller, you should check if the function `buttonPushed` might not be called on the device (just add a breakpoint or sth.)

Comment: Andreas Oetjen, it works if I activate the speechToText which is in another view controller and get back to my view controller and try the textToSpeech. That's really weird, looks like the speechToText activates the speaker of my phone, but that's no sense as if I switch to iTunes, for example, the volume of the device is ok.

Comment: Same here, did you find any solution or problem?

Comment: In case someone has the same problem, mine was solved by
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44343750/4140007)